# how to add the cutom row to the ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, header, footer

I am developing a simple android application,which is having a custom listview where iam having a image and beside that image name and description.I created a custom_list.xml in my layout folder and having a pictureListAdapter which adds the data to the imageview,textview,textview.This is my custom_list.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageName"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to load the data  and the list is fine,my problem is need to display the fixed header and footer to this list, i took a separate activity(MyActivity) and wrote the following code in MyCustomActivity.xml to add header and footer like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MyCustomActivity" >

  <include layout="@layout/header"
    android:id="@+id/hd"/>
  <include layout="@layout/activity_custom_list"
      android:id="@+id/listView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
  <include
    android:id="@+id/ft"
    layout="@layout/footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but header and footer or not coming in the screen, screen look like the same as before. Can anyone please give me a way as how to add header and footer for my Custom listview, I am having another doubt like whether I need to place a ListView tag in place of Middle include tag, if so then how to add the list to ListView tag.
please bear with me I am very new to android, Thanks

Comment: In your BaseAdapter you can test the cell number. if it is 0 or the last on you just use another Layout/object for the row

Comment: what does your `MyActivity` extend from?

Comment: @sunilMishra its MyCustomActivity not MyActivity(typing error) it extends from ListActivity, thanks for the early reply

Comment: Change `ListActivity` to `Activity`

Comment: @sunilMishra if i change it to Activity only header,one default list,footer is coming because i cannot call my listAdapter( setListAdapter(new PhotoViewerCustomAdapter(parentAct, imageDetails)))..did you see my point.

Comment: What does your adapter look like?

Answer (score 1):

Add the layout_weight attribute to the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MyCustomActivity" >

  <include layout="@layout/header"
    android:id="@+id/hd"/>
  <include layout="@layout/activity_custom_list"
      android:id="@+id/listView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight="1" />
  <include
    android:id="@+id/ft"
    layout="@layout/footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```